# Contiguous prime numbers with MPI (Want more ideas for an efficient algorithm)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am a programmer. I am working with Message Passing Interface (MPI) in C. I do a program that consist on finding the contiguous prime from 1 to 10,000,000.

I already do it! but I do it with trial division, testing the square root of the number to see if it is prime.

For example, to check for a number n, if it is prime:

```
int Isprime(int n){

for(i = 2; i <= ceil(sqrt(n)); i++)
{ 
   if(n%i == 0) 
       return 0;
} 

return 1; }
```

Meaning that if a number `i` which is less than or equal to the square root of a specified number, and `i` divides it, then the specified number is not prime.

Does someone know something more accurate? I mean more efficient to do this? Is there a more efficient algorithm to determine if a number is prime? Is there some important property of primes that I overlooked?

The run time of my program is good, but I want more! :)
Ideas?

Comment: [Miller-Rabin Primality Test](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test#C)

Comment: [Prime Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Prime_Sieve_of_Eratosthenes.c)

Comment: [scicomp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) would also gladly take your question; we take lots of questions on MPI, and on the practical implementation of parallel algorithms. (I'm a mod on scicomp.SE.)

Comment: hi Geoff Oxberry, Can you help me?

Comment: Math.SE mods: Cross post on [scicomp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1831/contiguous-prime-numbers-with-mpi-want-more-ideas-for-an-efficient-algorithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is just my opinion. I feel this question too broad, and off-topic for math.SE. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [CS.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) would be better venues to discuss methods and algorithms for primality testing, implementation-related issues, including parallelism.*

Anyways..

If you're looking for a simple method to find primes up to a certain bound, then you might want to *read* [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). In general, there are various methods for primality testing. You can *read* this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test). The fastest deterministic algorithms is AKS [*read* here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) but I doubt it's hard to implement. Miller-Rabin ([*read* here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)) is a probabilistic algorithm that is not hard to implement.

Comment: Thanks, but the Sieve of Eratoshthenes means that I have to make a list from 2 to 10,000,000. So that is not what I am searching for. The Miller-Rabin probabilistic algorithm... I just dont get what they are doing... (Taking abstract algebra now...) Anyways, Thanks for the info!